# Vue.js: Axios is not working in Vue when calling an API

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

Here is my code:

**Main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
var eventBus = new Vue();
Vue.prototype.$eventBus = eventBus;
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**Calling API**

```
methods:{
    loginMethode(){
        console.log(this.user);
        this.$eventBus.$emit("loadingStatus",true);
        this.$axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        });
        this.$eventBus.$emit("loadingStatus",false);
    }
  }
```

**It's showing an error message that**

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
> undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the error, because "$axios" object that you define inside a Main.js module is not defined inside your ./App.js module. You should pass it there somehow.
Consider to use vue mixins or component extention or composition API.

Comment: How to pass ? Give me an example please.

Comment: The simplest way is to import axios inside App.js:

`
import axios from 'axios'; 
`
and then using it as a regular module:

`
loginMethode(){
        ...
        axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        });
        ...
    }
`

Comment: I am using axios from my Login.vue file. How to import in .vue file ?
Ihave updated my full code from where I am using this axios.